# How to reduce the WPF applications ram consumption when removing a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a wpf application where I use UserControl to separate each window, for example login window, group messages,...

as the UserControl is no longer useful I remove it.

however I noticed that the ram when I remove the UserControl does not release all the memory of that UserControl.

**My Code**

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MyTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Width="1024"
        Height="576">
        
        <Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="UserTest">
                <local:User1 x:Name="MyUser1 Visibility="Visible"/>
                <local:User2 x:Name="MyUser2 Visibility="Visible"/>
                <local:User3 x:Name="MyUser3 Visibility="Visible"/>
                <local:User4 x:Name="MyUser4 Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </Grid>
            <Button Name="MyButton" Content="Remove" Click="TestRemove"/>
        <Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void TestRemove(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UserTest.Children.Remove(MyUser1);
    UserTest.Children.Remove(MyUser2);
    UserTest.Children.Remove(MyUser3);
    UserTest.Children.Remove(MyUser4);
}
```

My application currently open with all UserControl consumes about **290MB**

I noticed a difference in consumption when I disable UserControl in **XAML** and when I use `Children.Remove`

**Example:**

**When I disable UserControl like the one below, the ram reduces from 290MB to 150MB**

```
<Grid x:Name="UserTest">
      <!-- Disable
      <local:User1 x:Name="MyUser1 Visibility="Visible"/>
      -->

      <local:User2 x:Name="MyUser2 Visibility="Visible"/>
      <local:User3 x:Name="MyUser3 Visibility="Visible"/>
      <local:User4 x:Name="MyUser4 Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</Grid>
```

Now if I use `UserTest.Children.Remove(MyUser1);` **my ram reduces from 290MB to 210MB**

why this difference in ram, is this normal? Is there a way for the garbage collection to completely clean up the UserControl ram?

Comment: Are you forcing a GC.Collect after these tests? Otherwise you're at the mercy of the unpredictable Garbage Collector. Obviously when you disable it using a comment it never gets instantiated and so never uses the ram in the first place. When you use it and then remove the child though you have to consider GC.

Comment: @PeterMoore yes i got to use `GC.Collect()` after `UserTest.Children.Remove(MyUser4);` and I had the same result

Comment: Ok. So with WPF there are also a lot of native resources being consumed - Direct3D etc - that don't necessarily get freed on a GC. Ive seen this many times. You'll do everything correctly but see your ram usage keep increasing. Then suddenly it gets to s critical threshold and goes down. These are unpredictable beasts.  Are you getting out of memory exceptions or just curious?

Comment: @PeterMoore just out of curiosity. So I did a test and waited for an hour and the value of ram remained the same as I said, it is only varying between 8MB difference.

Comment: Commenting it out means it's never instantiated. How can you remove an instance doesn't exist?

Comment: @pablokentch what I've found is that Task Manager doesn't always show RAM fully released after the removal of UIElements until your app's overall usages gets to a high threshold. I believe this is a side effect of the way native (C/C++) code handles memory allocation. WPF also consumes VRAM which doesn't allocate or free the same way either. The best way to really know would be to use the Visual Studio performance tools. As long as your MANAGED memory usage does what you expect then you should be safe ignoring what Task Manager is telling you.